# Outlook Quick Steps appears twice in custom tab

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a custom Outlook 2016 tab that includes Quick Steps. Starting this week, the Quick Steps now display twice in the ribbon. It also happens with a new custom tab and profile. Resetting the customization and re-importing a backup didn't solve the issue, neither did deleting the custom steps. To add to the issue, the Quick Step in the `Home` tab displays normally.

[image: Custom Tab]
Custom Tab

[image: Home Tab]
Home Tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue in Version 1804, Build 9226.2082:
[image]

But it works fine in Version 1803, Build 9126.2152:
[image]

You may need to revert to the previous version in order to work around the problem:
[Revert to an earlier version of Office 2016 C2R](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic)

Comment: That is the version I am using. I also confirmed this issue with another person. It looks like a bug in the latest build.